# How do I raise or lower the position of text?

Tags: minipage, text-manipulation

Using minipage, I've split my header into

```
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\textsc{ \Huge{\textbf{MyNameHere}} }\\
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
   \begin{flushright}
   MyAddress\\
   MyPhone \bullet MyEmail
   \end{flushright}
\end{minipage}
```

However, the text of the items don't seem to be on even bases. In other words, the text in the left box seems to be "floating" a bit higher than the text on the right.

How can I raise the text in right box?

---

**Update:**
I tried using the optional argument `[b]` and adding `\noindent`

```
\noindent % to insert left mini page at left margin
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
    { \Huge{\textbf{MyNameHere}} }\\
\end{minipage}\hfill% don't leave empty spaces between the two minipages
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.6\textwidth}
    \begin{flushright}
        \faHome\ Address \textbullet\ CityStateZip \textbullet\ Country \\
        \faMobilePhone\ Phone \textbullet\ \faEnvelopeO\ E-mail \\ %[-0.2cm]
    \end{flushright}
\end{minipage}
```

But I still have this:
[image]
It might not be too clear b/c the background is white, but notice how MyNameHere is much higher.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two `minipage` environments can be aligned at different ways:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\begin{document}
\hrule

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\textsc{\Huge{\textbf{MyName A}}}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
   \raggedleft
   MyAddress\\
   MyPhone \textbullet\ MyEmail
\end{minipage}

\hrule

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
\textsc{\Huge{\textbf{MyName B}}}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\textwidth}
   \raggedleft
   MyAddress\\
   MyPhone \textbullet\ MyEmail
\end{minipage}

\hrule

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
\kern0pt
\textsc{\Huge{\textbf{MyName C}}}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\textwidth}
  \kern0pt
   \raggedleft
   MyAddress\\
   MyPhone \textbullet\ MyEmail
\end{minipage}

\hrule

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
\textsc{\Huge{\textbf{MyName D}}}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.6\textwidth}
  \kern0pt
   \raggedleft
   MyAddress\\
   MyPhone \textbullet\ MyEmail
\end{minipage}

\hrule

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
  \textsc{\Huge{\textbf{MyName E}}}
  \par\kern0pt
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.6\textwidth}
   \raggedleft
   MyAddress\\
   MyPhone \textbullet\ MyEmail
  \par\kern0pt
\end{minipage}

\hrule
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**A:** The `minipage`s are vertically centered.

**B:** The base lines of the top lines are aligned.

**C:** The top of the `minipage`s are aligned.

**D:** The base lines of the bottom lines are aligned.

**E:** The bottom of the `minipage`s are aligned.

Answer (score 2):

Use the optional argument:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
  \textsc{\Huge{\textbf{MyNameHere}} }
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\raggedleft
    MyAddress\\
    MyPhone $\bullet$ MyEmail
\end{minipage}

\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{2pt} 

\bigskip
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You probably want something like

```
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
\Huge\scshape MyNameHere
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.6\textwidth}
\raggedleft
 MyAddress\\
 MyPhone \textbullet\ MyEmail
\end{minipage}
```

No chance of getting bold small caps with the standard fonts.

But it's much better to use a `tabular`, which doesn't require guessing the widths.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\noindent
{\Huge\scshape\strut MyNameHere}\hfill
\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}r@{}}
 MyAddress\\
 MyPhone \textbullet\ MyEmail
\end{tabular} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Use `\textbullet\` as separator.

**2.** Use `\noindent` to insert the left mini page at the left margin.

**3.** Don't leave empty spaces between the mini pages. Note the use of `%`

**4.** Use the option `[b]` to align the boxes.

```
\noindent%
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
  \textsc{\Huge{\textbf{MyNameHere}}}
\end{minipage}%                        <----- here
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.6\textwidth}
   \begin{flushright}
   MyAddress\\
   MyPhone \textbullet\ MyEmail
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}
```

[image]

Comment: I did exactly as you said and it looks no different...

Answer (score 1):

A version with different proportions, to better see the bases of first lines in two columns (It is not clear if you have in mind the first lines or whole text). `\strut` makes a box of vertical size of `(` and null width.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
\textsc{ \Huge{\textbf{MyNameHere}} }\\
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
   \begin{flushright}
   \Huge\strut\normalsize MyAddress\\
   MyPhone $\bullet$ MyEmail
   \end{flushright}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```